# Is there a way to determine in SQL Server 2017 if there are duplicates within a column of a query and change that input?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am working on SQL Server 2017 writing a query that determines the emails of employees that looks like:

firstname.lastname123@email.com.

The three digits are part of their employee IDs.  (I did not pick this way to determine emails and cannot change it).

I am running into a problem where there just happens to be employees with the same name and have the same last three digits of their employee ID.  When this happens I need to add a number in sequencing order to the email to make them unique, i.e.,

**Examples:**

Name: John Doe, Employee ID: 00123 john.doe123@email.com

Name: John Doe, Employee ID: 12123 john.doe1231@email.com

Name: John Doe, Employee ID: 98123 john.doe1232@email.com

I do not need to assume there will be more than 10 of the same name and number so there should be no cases beyond having 4 digits within an email.  Also, the way it determines who has the lesser digits within their emails is by the order of the employee ID.  Who has the lower employee ID has the earlier email in the sequence described above.

The query that creates their email is simply pulling first name, last name, and last three digits of their ID and concatenating them together in a single column. (first + '.' + last + right(em_id,3) + 'email.com')

How/What can I implement in order to create the desired outcome described above if duplicates exist?

Comment: Hav you considered adding `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with `cast` function to turn it into varchar like this:

```
select (name + '.' 
        + surname 
        + right(Employee_ID,3) 
        + cast(row_number() over(partition by name, surname order by Employee_ID) as varchar) 
        + 'email.com') 
from employee
```

Wit this you will have results like :

- john.doe1231@email.com
- john.doe1232@email.com
- john.doe1233@email.com
- peter.peterson2441@email.com

And with this modification:

```
select case when row_number() over(partition by name, surname order by Employee_ID) > 1 
       then (name + '.' 
        + surname 
        + right(Employee_ID,3) 
        + cast(row_number() over(partition by name, surname order by Employee_ID)-1 as varchar) 
        + 'email.com')
       else (name + '.' 
        + surname 
        + right(Employee_ID,3)
        + 'email.com')
       end
from employee
```

You will get the results you have asked for.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9130c70e97df630968025f61aa5855a)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but all you really need is the count of "matching" emails that already exist.

```
DECLARE @emails TABLE (email VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @emails (email)
VALUES ('john.doe123@email.com'),('john.doe1231@email.com'),('john.doe1232@email.com');

DECLARE 
  @newbie VARCHAR(50) = 'john.doe123',
  @addy VARCHAR(50);

SELECT @addy = 
  CONCAT(@newbie,
         CASE WHEN CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(1)) = '0' THEN '' ELSE CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(1)) END)
FROM @emails
WHERE email LIKE CONCAT('%',@newbie,'%')

SELECT @addy;
```

Returns the email address without a suffix if there are no matches (that's the `CASE` expression at work), or adds the current count if there are some. Since the system is 0 based, there's no manipulation of the `COUNT` result needed.